# .htaccess redirect folders

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hello I have a link on my site with files at the following link: example.com/community/community/ How can I use htaccess to convert the link to example.com/community/ without moving the files from /community/community/

Comment: Any luck? Post some additional details if you can't get this working, otherwise please mark the question answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming example.com is the same domain where the site resides, and that `.htaccess` is in the domain root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^community/community/(.*)$ /community/$1 [L]
```